# Where can I find a list of available OS X "Extensions"?

Tags: macos

OS X Yosemite introduced Extensions, which are listed in the [Extensions](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18826?locale=en_US) panel in System Preferences. Currently, the list of "Actions" extensions on my OS X system contains only one item, "Markup".

How can I find more applications and utilities that can be installed as extensions? Is there a categorical list of extensions somewhere?

I tried searching the Mac App Store as well as Googling in general, but "extensions" is such a general term that it produces far too many unrelated results and makes it difficult to find true system extensions. Ideally, I'd like to find a list *specifically* about proper extensions (if such a list exists), or a better way to search for them (if there is one).

Comment: Have you gone to the App Store and searched using the word, _extension_?  Not that all apps listed in the search results may actually be an extension, e.g. with Xmenu it states "Operates as a menu extra, requires no hacks or extensions" however with Stat is says, "Finder extension now automatically updates icons in Finder if changes are detected.". So some of the search content will actually be an extension while some will say not an extension.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, that's exactly what I did. And what you describe is exactly the problem, and why I am looking for a list of extensions.

Comment: @user3439894 Perhaps the title of my question is too general. I will revise it.

Answer (score 9):

You can search the Mac App Store for apps supporting a specific extension type. For example, searching for `appex:com.apple.share-services` will show apps that support the share extension. Not all macOS apps are distributed through the Mac App Store, so this isn't an exhaustive list.

Common Mac Extension Types are listed below:

- Action: `com.apple.ui-services`
- Audio Unit: `com.apple.AudioUnit-UI`
- Content Blocker: `com.apple.Safari.content-blocker`
- Document Provider: `com.apple.fileprovider-ui`
- Finder Sync: `com.apple.FinderSync`
- Photo Editing: `com.apple.photo-editing`
- Share: `com.apple.share-services`
- Today: `com.apple.widget-extension`

Comment: This is really great! But I can't seem to get it to work in Mojave?

Comment: Tried on Catalina and sadly it doesn't work any more.