# Search iOS App Store by sharing features included with app

Tags: ios-appstore, search

iOS 8 introduced [sharing extensions](http://www.imore.com/sharing-ios-8-explained).

But what apps show up in what share lists?:

> *Activation rules* tells the system when to offer a particular app's extension. For example, when photos are selected, the activation rules for a photo app would tell iOS that it should be included in the options... [Apps] can and will all have different, if sometimes overlapping activation rules. Developers can indicate their activation rules by using a predicate with as simple or as detailed a query string as is needed.  [[same article]](http://www.imore.com/sharing-ios-8-explained).

I have an App that shares plain text files via the share button. (App is HoursTracker tho I don't think that's relevant).

So I want to search the App Store for an app that "activates" for plain text sharing extension. I don't want a cloud app (eg Dropbox). I've searched for hours, downloaded 20 [free] that seemed like they would, and none of them do.

One could imagine a generalized search function categorizing apps by what they share, and what sharing extensions they provide.

Is there a way?

Comment: I don't think Apple offers that type of advanced search like that.  I don't even think they offer that to 3rd-parties via api.

Comment: Also a tad ironic you ask this mere days after somebody else asked the same thing about [OS X/macOS](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251451/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-available-os-x-extensions).

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to search the App Store like that as Apple doesn't expose that data. Most apps don't even list the ability in their description text, so while you could try running a Google search, e.g. https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=site%3Aitunes.apple.com%20text%20share%20extension, unfortunately it won't work too well.

Comment: It doesnt work too well, Which is why I came here ;) Oh well, worth trying.

Comment: It would be a good idea and I would love to have it.  Perhaps you should let Apple know via their feedback page (I did this, also): https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: @fbara I did too. There was no "app store" on that page, so I submitted to iPhone.